# How to get selected values from custom drop-down using angularJS

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

actually I have been implemented one custom drop-down using `<ul>` & `<li>` elements in my application. And right now I am able to select dropdown values by using mouse click but as part of functionality requirement, user able to select the drop-down values by using enter key also. So for this, I have been binding `ng-keypress` directive along with `ng-mousedown` on `<li>` element but here I able to select the drop-down values using mouse click but not by entering enter key press. Please don't consider this question as duplicate as I asking this question after going through a number of existing threads and not get the perfect answer.And here I posting my whole code base too. Please have a look at it once. I big thanks in advance.

And here selected values just showing at above of search input field as below

[image]

Here is my code base -

```js
var appOne = angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute']);

appOne.directive('myEnter', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind("keydown keypress", function (event) {
            if (event.which === 13) {
                console.log("******From myEnter directive******");
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    };
});

appOne.controller('controllerOne', function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.seriesSelected = [];
    var i = 0;
    $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
        i++;
        var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
        var j = lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
        if (i === 5) {
            $scope.isShowDropDown();
            i = 0;
        }
        return j;
    }

    $scope.isShowDropDown = function () {
        var e1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#versionsId'));
        var k = 0;
        var column1RelArray = $('#versionsId li').map(function () {
            k++;
            if (k === 3) {
                return false;
            }
            return $(this).hasClass('versionValClass');
        });

        if (column1RelArray.length === 0) {

            e1.removeClass('open');
        }
        if (column1RelArray.length > 0) {

            e1.addClass('open');
        }
    }

    $scope.showDropDown = function (event) {
        var e1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#versionsId'));
        if (!e1.hasClass('open')) {
            e1.addClass('open');
        }
    }

    $scope.versionList1 = [
        {
            "id": "217233",
            "value": "16.1",
            "index": "0",
            "type": "Class"
        },
        {
            "id": "217220",
            "value": "12.2",
            "index": "1",
            "type": "Class"
        },
        {
            "id": "217229",
            "value": "13.7",
            "index": "2",
            "type": "Class"
        },
        {
            "id": "212675",
            "value": "8.123",
            "index": "3",
            "type": "Class"
        },
        {
            "id": "212689",
            "value": "16.123",
            "index": "4",
            "type": "Class"
        }
  ];
    $scope.versionList = $scope.versionList1.slice(0);

    $scope.selecteSeries = function (indx) {
        $scope.filterSeries.value = '';
        $scope.seriesSelected.push($scope.versionList[indx]);

    }


    $scope.selecteSeriesOnPressEnter = function (indx, event) {
        console.log("keycode is" + event.keyCode);
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $scope.filterSeries.value = '';
            $scope.seriesSelected.push($scope.versionList[indx]);
        }
    }

    $('ul#versionsId').on("mouseenter", "li", function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });



    $('input#searchField').keydown(function (e) {
        var $listItems = $('ul#versionsId li');
        var key = e.keyCode,
            $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
            $current;

        if (key != 40 && key != 38) return;

        $listItems.removeClass('selected');

        if (key == 40) // Down key
        {
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            } else {
                $current = $selected.next();
            }
        } else if (key == 38) // Up key
        {
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.last();
            } else {
                $current = $selected.prev();
            }
        }

        $current.addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js" role="application" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
    <style>
        .versionsId {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 28%;
            z-index: 99;
            border: 0 1px 1px 1px solid #ddd;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            min-height: 249px;
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #fff;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 52px;
        }
        
        #selectedVers {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        input:focus {
            outline: none;
            outline: 0;
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 2px solid;
        }
        
        .versionsId.open {
            display: block;
        }
        /*.versionsId li:hover {
            background: #aaa;
        }*/
        
        .selected {
            background: #aaa;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="appOne" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <div>
        <ul id="selectedVers">
            <li ng-repeat='s in seriesSelected'> {{ s.value }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <label>Search: <input id="searchField" ng-model="filterSeries.value" ng-keypress='showDropDown($event);' style="border:solid 0 0 1px 0;border-top-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 2px;border-left-width: 0px;"></label>

    <div>
        <ul id="versionsId" class="versionsId" style="padding-left: 4px;">
            <li ng-repeat='v in versionList | filter : filterSeries : startsWith' ng-class="{'selected': $first}" tabindex="{{versionList.indexOf(v)}}" class="versionValClass" ng-if='seriesSelected.indexOf(v) < 0 ' ng-mousedown='selecteSeries(versionList.indexOf(v))' ng-keypress='selecteSeriesOnPressEnter(versionList.indexOf(v), $event);'> {{ v.value }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I played a lot with angular to get any workaround on this but still no luck but for time being I was done something with JQuery.

This is code snippet -

```js
var appOne = angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute']);

appOne.controller('controllerOne', function ($scope, $filter, $http) {

    $scope.seriesSelected = [];
    var i = 0;
    $scope.startsWith = function (actual, expected) {
        i++;
        var lowerStr = (actual + "").toLowerCase();
        var j = lowerStr.indexOf(expected.toLowerCase()) === 0;
        if (i === 5) {
            $scope.isShowDropDown();
            i = 0;
        }
        return j;
    }


    $scope.isShowDropDown = function () {
        var e1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#versionsId'));
        var k = 0;
        var column1RelArray = $('#versionsId li').map(function () {
            k++;
            if (k === 3) {
                return false;
            }
            return $(this).hasClass('versionValClass');
        });

        if (column1RelArray.length === 0) {
            e1.removeClass('open');
        }
        if (column1RelArray.length > 0) {
            e1.addClass('open');
        }
    }

    $scope.showDropDown = function (event) {
        var e1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#versionsId'));
        if (!e1.hasClass('open')) {
            e1.addClass('open');
        }
    }

    $scope.selecteSeries = function (indx) {
        $scope.filterSeries.value = '';
        $scope.seriesSelected.push($scope.versionList[indx]);

    }


    $('ul#versionsId').on("mouseenter", "li", function () {
        $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    });



    $keypresselm = undefined;
    $('input#searchField').keydown(function (e) {
        var $listItems = $('ul#versionsId li');
        var key = e.keyCode,
            $selected = $listItems.filter('.selected'),
            $current;

        if (key != 40 && key != 38 && key != 13) return;

        $listItems.removeClass('selected');

        if (key == 40) // Down key
        {
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':last-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            } else {
                $current = $selected.next();
            }
            //  $keypresselm = $current;
        } else if (key == 38) // Up key
        {
            if (!$selected.length || $selected.is(':first-child')) {
                $current = $listItems.last();
            } else {
                $current = $selected.prev();
            }
            //$keypresselm = $current;
        } else if (key == 13) {
            $current = $listItems.eq(0);
            var ind = $keypresselm.attr('key');
            var e1 = angular.element(document.querySelector('#versionsId'));
            e1.removeClass('open');
            $scope.seriesSelected.push($scope.versionList[ind]);
            $scope.filterSeries.value = '';
            $scope.$apply();

        }
        
        $keypresselm = $current;
        if ($current !== undefined) {
            $current.addClass('selected');
        }

    });

    
    $scope.versionList1 = [
        {
            "id": "217233",
            "value": "16.1",
            "index": "0",
            "type": "Class"
            },
        {
            "id": "217220",
            "value": "12.2",
            "index": "1",
            "type": "Class"
            },
        {
            "id": "217229",
            "value": "13.7",
            "index": "2",
            "type": "Class"
            },
        {
            "id": "212675",
            "value": "8.123",
            "index": "3",
            "type": "Class"
            },
        {
            "id": "212689",
            "value": "16.123",
            "index": "4",
            "type": "Class"
            }
      ];

    $scope.versionList = $scope.versionList1.slice(0);

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-filter-filter-production</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myApp.js"></script>
    <style>
        .versionsId {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            width: 28%;
            z-index: 99;
            border: 0 1px 1px 1px solid #ddd;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            min-height: 249px;
            max-height: 250px;
            overflow: auto;
            background: #fff;
            margin-top: 0px;
            margin-left: 52px;
        }
        
        #selectedVers {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        
        input:focus {
            outline: none;
            outline: 0;
            border: 0;
            border-bottom: 2px solid;
        }
        
        .versionsId.open {
            display: block;
        }
        /*.versionsId li:hover {
            background: #aaa;
        }*/
        
        .selected {
            background: #aaa;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body ng-app="appOne" ng-controller="controllerOne">
    <div>
        <ul id="selectedVers">
            <li ng-repeat='s in seriesSelected'> {{ s.value }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <label>Search: <input id="searchField" ng-model="filterSeries.value" ng-keypress='showDropDown();' style="border:solid 0 0 1px 0;border-top-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 2px;border-left-width: 0px;"></label>

    <div>
        <ul id="versionsId" class="versionsId" style="padding-left: 4px;">
            <li ng-repeat='v in versionList | filter : filterSeries : startsWith' ng-class="{'selected': $first}" class="versionValClass" ng-if='seriesSelected.indexOf(v) < 0 ' ng-mousedown='selecteSeries(versionList.indexOf(v))' key="{{versionList.indexOf(v)}}">{{ v.value }} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div>
        <!--<label>SearchOne: <input ng-onkeyup="keyup()"></label>-->
        <!--<label>SearchOne: <input ui-event="{keyup: 'myFn($event)'}" style="border:solid 0 0 1px 0;border-top-width: 0px;border-right-width: 0px;border-bottom-width: 2px;border-left-width: 0px;"></label>-->
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```